# How to solve ajax post while hosting a mvc 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-hosting

I am hosting a MVC3 application in IIS7. The aplication got hosted but ajax post is not working in the application.

Could Anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hardcoded the urls in your javascript, haven't you?

For example you wrote:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Ajax',
    success: function() {

    }
});
```

instead of using url helpers:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Ajax", "Home")',
    success: function() {

    }
});
```

Also you probably have hardcoded script locations:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/somscript.js"></script>
```

instead of using url helpers:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/somscript.js")"></script>
```

Now go ahead through your code and replace all urls that you have hardcoded with ones generated with helpers.

The reason your code doesn't work when you host it in IIS is because you host your application in a virtual directory. So the correct path is no longer `/Home/Index` but `/SomeAppName/Home/Index`. The best way top ensure that your application will work in all environments no matter where it is hosted is to always use url helpers.